# Android check box tik mark disappear randomly when moving from one fragment to another using android-material-stepper

Tags: android

Instead of getting checkbox like this(i am getting it only few times randomly when moving from on fragment to another).
[image]
I am getting like this(checkbox is still true but only tik mark is missing randomly)
[image]
I am using `onSaveInstanceState` and `onViewStateRestored`. The problem is the `checkbox` tik mark only disappears and comes back few times but the state of `checkbox` is still selected i see blue color around all the selected check boxes that selected color doesn't go away only the tik mark goes away and comes back randomly.

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_tv"
            android:text="TV"
            android:theme="@style/CheckBoxTheme"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Tv" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

My Fragment:

```
public class StepFragmentTwo extends Fragment implements BlockingStep {
    private static final String CLICKS_KEY = "clicks";

    private static final String TAG = "ADERVERTISMENT";

    private int i = 0;
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    CheckBox c;
    Boolean tv = false ;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(getLayoutResId(), container, false);
        c = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        //initialize your UI
        return v;
    }

    protected int getLayoutResId() {
        return getArguments().getInt(String.valueOf(R.layout.step2));
    }


    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putInt(CLICKS_KEY, i);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if(outState!=null) {
            outState.putBoolean("c", c.isChecked());

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);

        if(savedInstanceState!=null) {
            tv = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("c");

        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        c.setChecked(tv);

    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    public void onNextClicked(final StepperLayout.OnNextClickedCallback callback) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (c.isChecked()) {
                  tv = true;
                }

                SharedPreferences shared = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();

                editor.putBoolean("tv", tv);

                editor.apply();     // This line is IMPORTANT !!!

                callback.goToNextStep();

            }
        }, 200L);
    }

    @Override
    @UiThread
    public void onCompleteClicked(final StepperLayout.OnCompleteClickedCallback callback) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                callback.complete();
            }
        }, 2000L);
    }

    public static StepFragmentTwo newInstance(@LayoutRes int layoutResId) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(String.valueOf(R.layout.step2), layoutResId);
        StepFragmentTwo fragment = new StepFragmentTwo();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
    @Override
    public VerificationError verifyStep() {
        //return null if the user can go to the next step, create a new VerificationError instance otherwise
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSelected() {
        //update UI when selected
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull VerificationError error) {
        //handle error inside of the fragment, e.g. show error on EditText
    }

    public void onBackClicked(StepperLayout.OnBackClickedCallback callback) {
        //Toast.makeText(this.getContext(), "Your custom back action. Here you should cancel currently running operations", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        callback.goToPrevStep();
    }
}
```

Comment: In onResume get tv and set to checkbox.

Comment: @rajahsekar i already done that you can see my onResume method in Fragment.

Comment: yes i have seen it but your not fetching tv. tv is in your sharedfrerence you can get it and set to check box.

Answer (score 0):

In short you can do,

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
           SharedPreferences shared = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Mypref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
           SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
           tv = editor.getBoolean("tv", tv);
           c.setChecked(tv);

    }
```

Comment: I am not sure but you can try once remove theme and custom drawable and check it. there might be problem in that.

Comment: @rajasekar there is no problem in getting value, some problem with theme or checkbox view, i have updated my question see if you can help further.